# DesktopAppConverter does not recognize installed files into roaming folder

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

The Setup created by InnoSetup is installing two files into the Roaming Directory. For example:

> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\Get\Rezeptverwaltung\zutaten.xml
>   C:\Users{user}\AppData\Roaming\Get\Rezeptverwaltung\rezepte.xml

I also can see the following directory when using the DesktopAppConverter

> C:\temp\Recipe\PackageFiles\VFS\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\Get\Rezeptverwaltung\rezepte.xml
>   C:\
>   temp\Recipe\PackageFiles\VFS\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Roaming\Get\Rezeptverwaltung\zutaten.xml

When installing the Recipe.appx the required files (C:\Users{userprofile}\AppData\Roaming\Get\Rezeptverwaltung*.xml
are not installed into the userprofile Roaming directory.

How can I tell the DesktopAppConverter to install this files too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When installing the Recipe.appx the required files (C:\Users{userprofile}\AppData\Roaming\Get\Rezeptverwaltung*.xml are not installed into the userprofile Roaming directory.

These files have been redirected to the local app data store:

```
VFS/USERS/ContainerAdministrator/AppData/Roaming/xxxx
```

[image]

Please see the points listed in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare)

**Your app writes to the AppData folder with the intention of sharing data with another app.** After conversion, AppData **is redirected to the local app data store**, which is a private store for each UWP app. Use a different means of inter-process data sharing. For more info, see [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data).